# Project doesn't build for iphone simulator.

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

I get this error while trying to build for iphone simulator:

```
    d: warning: ignoring file /users/salehshah/SmartSwipe/libANMobilePaymentLib.a, file was    built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386) Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

Please note that i am using xcode 4.2 with iOS 5. Project builds and runs fine on device. I think there is some problem while linking the static library. May be it is problem with the architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static library you are linking is not compiled for the simulator. If this is a precompiled library you would want to create a version, that includes all three iOS architectures armv6 armv7 and i386. You can do so by compiling every single architecture on their own and then linking them together using lipo see `man lipo`

If on the other hand you are compiling the library as a dependency of your app target, something is wrong with your build settings. Have a look a the libraries build settings, namely the `ARCHS` and the `VALID_ARCHS`

Comment: it was running fine on the simulator as well. Suddenly it stopped running, i didn't change any project settings etc.

Comment: So if you didn't change anything, there's no need to look at these settings. You are probably hit by a cosmic ray. ;-) Take a look at the Log Navigator (Cmd-7) after building. Is the library built? Is it built for the right architecture (namely i386)?

Comment: it gives this warning :file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Comment: Great, we had that. I was trying to help you find out WHY it is not being built for the architecture being linked. But if you don't answer my questions, I can't. Again take a look at the Log Navigator. It lists all recent builds. Click on the topmost item saying "Build <YourApp>". At the right side click "all" in the upper left corner and "All messages" to the right of it. It should now list all targets that were built during the building of your app. Is the library in question amongst those? What dose it say about the Destination and the SDK the library was built for? BTW tried a clean build?

Comment: finally i was able to make it work, the static library was built for iphone device thats why it didn't run on the simulator. Compiled a copy for simulator and it worked.